# for loop declaration using pointers in C

Tags: c, loops, pointers, struct

There are two `for` loops that I have a question about.

I'm fairly new to using linked lists and pointers. I saw some code that attempts to insert data into the linked lists using a `for` loop. However, the `for` loop declaration is totally foreign to me and I don't understand how it works.

My understanding of a typical for loop comprises 3 parts:

1. Declare the iterator
2. Loop condition
3. increment/decrement the iterator

Example:

```
main()
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //do something....
  }
}
```

Below is some of the code that I'm hoping will help you understand what I'm looking at.

```
struct labellist {
  int x;
  int y;
  struct labellist *nextlabel;
  struct labeltest *testsptr;
};

struct labellist *labelptr;
struct labeltest {
  int z;
  struct labeltest *nexttest;
};
```

#### Loop 1:

```
for(q = &labelptr; *q; q = &((*q)->nextlabel)) {
```

#### Loop 2:

```
for(q = &labelptr, count=0; *q && count< MAXTUBES; q = &((*q)->nextlabel), count++)
```

What do these statements really mean?

Edit: Thanks for the replies so far. I understand what both loops are doing now. What took me some time to understand was the two initializing variables pointer q and int count; for(q = &labelptr, count=0;.

I wasn't used to seeing two declarations in the initialization section of a for loop before but its clear now. Thank you!

Comment: You appear to be getting downvotes because you never *actually* ask a question. What *exactly* did you want to know? And why didn't a C language book or website answer it for you?

Comment: If you change the "increment/decrement" part in the (3) to "update", your code will totally fit into it. And have a look at [Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: Your C++ tag is misleading.  Almost any C code can be C++ code, but your code would be such terrible style if it were C++ rather than C, that you shouldn't have the C++ tag on the question.

Comment: Your item (1) is just an option that isn't even available in ANSI C.  Item (1) should be initialize the "iterator" (old C meaning of that word, not C++ meaning).  Declaring the iterator there is a newer C option, and even initialing it there is optional.  Declaring or both declaring and initializing could occur before the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Some references for future use. Also see the C tag wiki. Just hover over the C tag, then click "info" at the bottom.

- http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-for-Statement
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3e6x17s.aspx

Quick summary here:

- `q = &labelptr`
  This is setting q to point at labelptr at the beginning of the loop.
- `*q`
  This has to be true for the loop to continue. When `*q` is false the loop ends. `*q` will be false when q points to something that is a NULL pointer or zero (aka NULL).
- `q = &((*q)->nextlabel)`
  This gets the address of (`*q)->nextlabel`

That for loop walks down a linked list until it reaches a NULL pointer. Simple really.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write

```
for (initializer;  test;  update)
    body;
```

as

```
initializer;
while (test) {
   body;
   update;
}
```

and that sometimes makes them easier to read.

#### Loop 1:

```
for (q = &labelptr;  *q;  q = &((*q)->nextlabel))
```

`q` starts off pointing at `labelptr`;  while `q` is not null, execute the body, then move `q` to the next label by following the `nextlabel` pointer.

#### Loop 2:

```
for (q = &labelptr, count=0;
     *q && count < MAXTUBES;
     q = &((*q)->nextlabel), count++)
```

almost the same thing, but keep count as we go, and exit the loop if it reaches `MAXTUBES` iterations.